# Mac OS X and BlackBerry Desktop Manager

Tags: mac, blackberry

I would like to know if there is any way of installing the newest BB software using the Mac version of the BlackBerry Desktop Manager.

Answer (score 0):

When you asked this, the answer was no. However, version 2 allows for updates to the handheld code.

http://us.blackberry.com/apps-software/desktop/desktop_mac.jsp